# On a planet whose waters are super rich in iron, could life forms use the iron as a basis for their skeletons?

Tags: xenobiology, chemistry, biochemistry

One of my planets has surface waters that are incredibly rich in oxidized iron, and I was intrigued by the possibility of alternate materials for bones when I came across Stephen Gillett's Clorox planet where the animal bones and tree trunks are made of stuff like PVC due to the excess of chlorine in the atmosphere, so I was wondering, is there any iron-based material (short of literally just iron / steel) that organisms could use as a hydroxyapatite-analogue?

Comment: If the iron is oxidized, wouldn't the oceans be red? Which is kinda cool.

Comment: @Martamo Yes actually! The oceans are red and the landmasses are purple due to the native plant life.

Comment: What is the solar mass of the star?

Comment: @Martamo Two stars actually, the planet orbits a binary of 1.07 and 0.75 solar masses.

Comment: It's been a very long time since my chemistry classes, so I can't proffer this as an answer, but I believe the easy answer is "no" to both your questions (BTW, please note that you're allowed to ask one and only one question. Your title and the body of your post ask two. Related, but still two.) Calcium is an alkaline earth metal, so *theoretically* you could replace it with one of the other alkaline earth metals: beryllium, magnesium, strontium, barium & radium. However, I'd prefer someone with more recent experience confirm this.

Comment: BTW, please remember to not take supposition as fact. What Dr. Gillett did was propose an interesting planetary ecology - but humanity has no actual proof of any form of life other than what's on Earth. Thus, he's not proposing a truth, or a theory, or even a hypothesis. It's merely clever - and very fictional.

Comment: Wasn't that one of the stages of life on Earth? I seem to remember mentions of oceans with huge amounts of dissolved iron, and then some new organism evolving that pumped out oxygen, oxidising the whole lot, making it fall out of solution (iron oxide is HIGHLY insoluble in water). So it doesn't sound like a stable environment, unless you prohibit oxygen build-up in your seas/atmosphere.

Answer (score 6):

Yes!

There is a [snail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scaly-foot_gastropod) that uses iron (iron sulfides to be exact) as part of it's shells. While normally shells are calcium based.

I don't know how it would work. I cannot say for certain that it is possible. But one creature on earth has done something similar so it is plausible and believable.